# Failing to populate column 'method' in a factory

Tags: ruby, factory-bot, factories

I need to define a factory for a database table which contains column named 'method'.

I've tried something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :notification_baby_offset, class:'NotificationTemplate' do
    ...
    method {{ 'email' => false, 'notification' => true }}
    ...
  end
end
```

But, when I tried to build it, I got an error saying:

```
`method': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

It appears to identify 'method' as a function rather than a database column. I tried to emphasize this by `:method` or `"method"`, but that didn't work.

So, I have to build this factory like this for it to work:

```
FactoryGirl.create(:notification_baby_offset, method: { 'email' => false, 'notification' => true })
```

Is where a way to avoid this hack and define this column properly in a factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :notification_baby_offset, class:'NotificationTemplate' do
    ...
    after(:build) do |notification|
      notification.method = { 'email' => false, 'notification' => true }
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

Or even (if your `new` supports passing attributes):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :notification_baby_offset, class:'NotificationTemplate' do
    ...
    initialize_with { new(method: { 'email' => false, 'notification' => true }) }
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice! Worked like a charm. Thank you